# How to find where are defined tokens for Redirect?

Tags: 8, redirection, tokens

After enabling *Token* and *Redirect* modules, I've found at `/admin/help/token` that I can use *Redirect* tokens. For example:

[image: Redirect tokens in Drupal at /admin/help/token]

However, I've got the problem finding the place where and how these tokens are defined (which file and hook or class).

Any ideas?

---

I've tried to search inside all files in docroot, e.g.

```
$ grep -r "The URL of the redirect" .
(nothing)
$ grep -r "The URL of the" .
(returns everything apart of redirect, no matching placeholders found)
$ grep -r token modules/contrib/redirect/
modules/contrib/redirect/config/install/views.view.redirect.yml:          tokenize: false
modules/contrib/redirect/modules/redirect_404/config/install/views.view.redirect_404.yml:          tokenize: false
modules/contrib/redirect/modules/redirect_404/redirect_404.routing.yml:    _csrf_token: 'TRUE'
modules/contrib/redirect/src/EventSubscriber/RouteNormalizerRequestSubscriber.php:      // Strip off query parameters added by the route such as a CSRF token.
$ grep -r redirect modules/contrib/token/
modules/contrib/token/src/Controller/TokenCacheController.php:   * Clear caches and redirect back to the frontpage.
modules/contrib/token/src/Controller/TokenCacheController.php:    return $this->redirect('<front>');
$ find modules/contrib/redirect modules/contrib/token -name "*.tokens.inc"
modules/contrib/token/tests/modules/token_module_test/token_module_test.tokens.inc
modules/contrib/token/token.tokens.inc (Note: nothing here for redirect)
```

So basically I couldn't find the source which module is defining those. This can help me in order to find out, why some of them aren't working as expected.

---

The main reason I ask this, because I would expect for redirect URL such as `/foo/XXX`, to return `XXX` when using `[redirect:url:args:last]`, but these tokens aren't populated at all.

Comment: `redirect` is an entity type - tokens are provided for its base and other fields automagically

Comment: Does it mean these tokens are populated and parsed by the core?

Comment: Yes exactly that @kenorb. Or maybe by the contrib token module in some cases. But not by the module that defines the entity type

Comment: Pretty confusing, as I was expecting that `[redirect:url:args:last]` will give me the last part of the URL of the redirect path, but it doesn't work at all. So making redirect like `/foo/XXX`, I would expect that `[redirect:url:args:last]` would return me `XXX`. However, since these are dynamically created somewhere in core, I think they're useless then.

Comment: That example would work if the route was defined as `foo/{arg}`. But if the route is `foo/bar`, static, then it doesn’t contain any parameters, so the token would be empty

Comment: Since this question is focused on where/how the tokens are defined for _Redirect_, I've posted [another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/273528/1908) focusing on the specific problem which I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Clive mentioned, since Redirect is an entity, those tokens are automatically generated by the Token module's [token.tokens.inc](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/token/tree/token.tokens.inc).

I suggest you read [Custom Tokens in Drupal 8](https://michaeltroutt.com/custom-tokens-in-drupal-8/) to understand how they are declared & work.