# How to dynamically redirect user from /foo/X to /bar/X?

Tags: 8, redirection, tokens

So far I did the following:

1. I've installed *Redirect* and *Token* modules.
2. I've applied [the patch for *Redirect* module to support wildcards](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/2831605).
3. I've applied [the patch for *Redirect* module to implement `hook_redirect_response_alter`](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/2909182).
4. I've defined the following `hook_redirect_response_alter` to [support and parse the tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/1331582).

   ```
   use Drupal\redirect\Entity\Redirect;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
   use Drupal\Component\Utility\UrlHelper;

   /**
    * Implements hook_redirect_response_alter().
    */
   function MYMODULE_redirect_response_alter(RedirectResponse $response, Redirect $redirect) {
     $uri = $redirect->getRedirect()['uri']; // "internal:/bar/[current-page:url:args:last]"
     if (!empty($uri) && strpos($uri, '[') !== FALSE) {
       $uri = \Drupal::token()->replace($uri); // "internal:/bar/"
       $external = UrlHelper::isValid($uri, TRUE); // bool
       $redirect->setRedirect($external ? $uri : explode('/', $uri, 2)[1]);
       $response->setTargetUrl($redirect->getRedirectUrl()->setAbsolute()->toString()); // "http://localhost/bar/"
     }
   }
   ```
5. I've added the following redirect at `/admin/config/search/redirect`:

   - From: `foo/*`
   - To: `/bar/[current-page:url:args:last]`

Based on the above, I'm expecting that typing `foo/X` will redirect to `bar/X`, and `foo/Y` to `bar/Y` accordingly, and so on. However, the above token is replaced with an empty string. Similar thing when using token such as `[current-page:url:args:value:2]`, it's not replaced at all. I've also learned [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/273504/1908) that using `[redirect:url:args:last]` won't work either, as the token is generated based on the entity type, so *Redirect* module isn't aware of it.

I've tried a few more tokens found at `/admin/help/token` which can potentially extract the second argument from the path, but I haven't found any suitable or working as expected for this task.

For example:

[image: Redirect tokens in Drupal 8 at /admin/help/token]
[image: Current page tokens in Drupal 8 at /admin/help/token]

---

#### More details

Applying `$redirect` context for token's `replace()` method, as suggested in the comments, didn't work as expected.

So the following line:

```
$uri = \Drupal::token()->replace($uri, ['redirect' => $redirect]);
```

populates some token with `redirect` prefix, however it wrongly replaces the current path, e.g. `[redirect:url:args:join:/]` becomes `admin/config/search/redirect/edit/25` for every page.

I've also tried to populate context for the `current-page` tokens, but it was requiring the current path exists, however during redirect the current path doesn't exist in the menu routing table, so it can't be loaded (I've tried `Url::createFromRequest()` and `\Drupal::request()`).

---

#### Question

What I'm missing? Is there any easier way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: You might need to explicitly replace the token : `$redirect->setRedirect(token_replace($uri, array('redirect' => $redirect)));`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've missed one line: `$uri = \Drupal::token()->replace($uri);` (copy & paste error), I had it in the original code. I can check if adding the argument can make the difference.

Comment: @EricLavault Yes, I think something started to behave differently (the `[redirect:...]` token being populated). I've used `[redirect:url:args:join:,]` to test it out, and at `/foo/X` page it's populated as `internal:/bar/|admin,config,search,redirect,edit,25`, it's like it's on the edit page, when it's not, weird. Altered line: `$uri = \Drupal::token()->replace($uri, ['redirect' => $redirect]);`. Could it be a bug?

Comment: Maybe I could use `[current-page:url:args:last]`/`[current-page:url:args:join:,]` instead, but it comes empty, and not sure which argument I can pass to `token()->replace()`?

Comment: You can redirect in a custom event subscriber, see  https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014

Comment: Just a wild guess. Because you're doing a redirect the current-page tokens do not get a chance to fire. Because /foo/X does not belong to the Redirect entity, those tokens do not get fired either. You'll have to debug and see if anything in my wild guess is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since passing context for token's `replace` method didn't work as expected, I've defined a new token in my custom module to return the specific components of the Drupal path (using the following [guide](https://michaeltroutt.com/custom-tokens-in-drupal-8/)).

#### `my_redirect.tokens.inc`

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * An include file defining custom tokens.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;

/**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function my_redirect_token_info() {
  $type = [
    'name' => t('Custom URL token for redirect'),
    'description' => t('Tokens helpful for redirect pages.'),
  ];

  $node['url-arg'] = [
    'name' => t("URL Argument"),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
    'description' => t('Returns a component of the current Drupal path.'),
  ];

  return [
    'types' => ['my_redirect' => $type],
    'tokens' => ['my_redirect' => $node],
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function my_redirect_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {

  $replacements = [];

  if ($type == 'my_redirect') {
    if ($argTokens = \Drupal::token()->findWithPrefix($tokens, 'url-arg')) {
      foreach ($argTokens as $arg => $original) {
        $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
        if ($arg === "first") {
          $value = explode('/', $current_path)[1];
        }
        elseif ($arg === "last") {
          $value = end(explode('/', $current_path));
        }
        else {
          $value = explode('/', $current_path)[$arg ?: 0];
        }
        $replacements[$original] = $value;
      }
    }
  }

  return $replacements;
}
```

So after applying already mentioned patches, and above code, I can use the following Redirect rule:

- From: `foo/*`
- To: `/bar/[my_redirect:url-arg:2]`